# Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix

Tags: r, error-handling, panel, var

I tried running panel var regression in R, but got this error

```
dataset1 <- pvargmm(dependent_vars = c("Income Inequality"),lags = 2, exog_vars = c("Age Dependency ratio", "private credit by financial sector", "inf", "gcf", "gdp", "agri emp", "govt exp", "Pop growth", "total emp", "capital openess", "secondary enrollement", "Trade to GDP", "Portfolio equity assets (stock)", "Portfolio equity liabilities (stock)", "FDI assets (stock)","FDI liabilities (stock)", "Debt assets (stock)","Debt liabilities (stock)", "financial derivatives (assets)", "financial derivatives (liab)", "FX Reserves minus gold" ), transformation = fd, data = High_Development_countries, panel_identifier = c("Year", "country"), steps = c("twostep"))

Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
Backtrace:
  1. panelvar::pvargmm(...)
  3. base::sort.default(unique(Set_Vars[, 1]))
  7. base::order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)
  8. base::lapply(z, function(x) if (is.object(x)) as.vector(xtfrm(x)) else x)
  9. base:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 12. base::xtfrm.default(x)
 14. base::rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep")
 16. tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, !nas)
 17. tibble:::check_names_df(i, x)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. \-panelvar::pvargmm(...)
  2.   +-base::sort(unique(Set_Vars[, 1]))
  3.   \-base::sort.default(unique(Set_Vars[, 1]))
  4.     +-x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]
  5.     +-tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing))
  6.     | \-tibble:::check_names_df(i, x)
  7.     \-base::order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)
  8.       \-base::lapply(z, function(x) if (is.object(x)) as.vector(xtfrm(x)) else x)
  9.         \-base:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 10.           +-base::as.vector(xtfrm(x))
 11.           +-base::xtfrm(x)
 12.           \-base::xtfrm.default(x)
 13.             +-base::as.vector(rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep"))
 14.             \-base::rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep")
 15.               +-x[!nas]
 16.               \-tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, !nas)
 17.                 \-tibble:::check_names_df(i, x)
```

Comment: somewhere you're using a matrix inside a `[` function call, where it's expecting a vector. Without seeing any data or code it's impossible to tell where this is happening.

Comment: The first line the code that I have written, and data is arranged as panel data

Comment: dataset1 <- pvargmm(dependent_vars = c("Income Inequality"),lags = 2,exog_vars = c("Age Dependency ratio", "private credit by financial sector", "inf", "gcf", "gdp", "agri emp", "govt exp", "Pop growth", "total emp", "capital openess", "secondary enrollement", "Trade to GDP", "Portfolio equity assets", "Portfolio equity liabilities", "FDI assets","FDI liabilities", "Debt assets","Debt liabilities", "financialderivatives...23", "financialderivatives...24", "FX Reserves minus gold" ), transformation = fd, data = High_Development_countries, panel_identifier = c("Year", "country"))

Comment: Add minimal data to run your code, and list the libraries.

Comment: Try `transformation = "fd"` instead of `transformation = fd`

Comment: Tried it, the same issue, Infact I changed the names the command wont run.

Comment: dataset2 <- pvargmm(dependent_vars = [c("A"),lags = 2, exog_vars = c("B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")], transformation = "fd", data = HDC, panel_identifier = c("Year", "country"), steps = c("twostep"), system_instruments = FALSE, collapse = FALSE)

Comment: what is `pvargmm` ?
Don't add extra content in a comment, edit your question.